# React native, using selectable style to make a dropdown picker on top of all views makes it untouchable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dropdown

I have a certain dropdown view that I want to stay on top of all other views. It currently looks like this.

[image]

I've tried setting a style of "elevation: 1" which fixes the UI but the dropdown stays untouchable if there were originally views on top of it.

[image]

The area that's not clickable should be clickable as well:

[image]

To explain it more using [a gif](https://imgur.com/QkYRL30).

Here's the [github issue link with the code](https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/issues/50).

Edit: Toggling the inspector on and off fixes the issue. But it's not a viable solution for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrapped the dropdown picker and the below components under a ScrollView with a nestedScrollEnabled and it's working.

```
<ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} />
    <DropDownPicker  ... />
</ScrollView>
```